# Flutter FutureBuilder using Supabase query

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-database

I'm unable to get Supabase queries working with flutter. Here is an example of the code:

```
child: FutureBuilder<PostgrestResponse<dynamic>>(
   future: supabase.from('products').select().execute(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.active) {
            return const Center(
               child: SizedBox(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                  ),
               );
            } else {
               return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate:
                      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: gridColumns,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                      ),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length, // this line is causing an error
                      ...
```

I have no idea how to turn the length of the snapshot. It is was to turn this to streambuilder it would work. So really all i'm after is a basic example of using a futurebuilder with supabase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if (snapshot.hasData)` instead of checking snapshots connection state. Because it would be not including any data and connection state is not active.

So you can change your code as;

```dart
child: FutureBuilder<PostgrestResponse<dynamic>>(
   future: supabase.from('products').select().execute(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(
               child: SizedBox(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                  ),
               );
            } else {
               return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate:
                      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: gridColumns,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                      ),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length, // this line is causing an error
                      ...
```

Comment: Thanks Mehmet, ok made that change but still unsure how you would output an itemCount for the builder?

Comment: Can you show inside your `PostgrestResponse` class, probably you need to get length of some property inside it

Answer (score 0):

While debugging the code, the response is coming as `snapshot.data.data`

[image]

So, the count value can be obtained by

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.data?.length,
```